# Collections "sort()" method prints out the addresses of the objects

Tags: java, list, comparison, comparable

I was reading this article about Comparator and Comparable in Java.

https://www.baeldung.com/java-comparator-comparable

Then I tried to do the Comparable code example myself. The goal was to:

I. Create a List:

```
List<Player> footballTeam = new ArrayList<>();
```

II. Create and add Player objects to the List

```
Player player1 = new Player(56, "Yousef",23);
Player player2 = new Player(34, "Sonny",27);
Player player3 = new Player(87, "Jamal",19);

footballTeam.add(player1);
footballTeam.add(player2);
footballTeam.add(player3);
```

III. Sort the list, using the Collections' sort() method

```
Collections.sort(footballTeam);
```

IV. Print the list

```
System.out.println("After Sorting : " + footballTeam);
```

V. End up with this result printed out in the console:

> After Sorting : [Steven, John, Roger]

But instead I got the following result:

> After sorting: [*6*.Player@4eec7777, *6*.Player@3b07d329,
> *6*.Player@41629346]

I managed to fix the problem by replacing this code:

```
System.out.println("After Sorting : " + footballTeam);
```

With a for loop:

```
for(Player p: footballTeam){
        System.out.print(p.getName() + ", ");
    }
```

But I don't think this is the right thing to do.
How am I supposed to get the same result as in the article, without a for loop?

All of my code, which tried to replicate the example (2 Classes)
https://pastebin.com/u/14nikolov/1/jXx8Grx6

Comment: Add a `toString()` method to your `Player` class.

Comment: @RobSpoor Thank you, this solved the problem. I am sorry for making a duplicate question, I really did spend a good amount of time trying to find the solution before asking the question, but it looks like I was not able to formulate my question well enough.